# Why Java has so many parse methods?

Tags: java, overriding, parameterized-types

For example the Math.max( .. .. ) method is overloaded to support different types of **Number**. One name for all of them because, no mather the type of **Number**, it does the same thing. 

So does the parse*NumberType* methods defined for each class extending **Number**. 

Why is it the way it is ? Wouldn't have been better if a parameterized parse method was defined in Number ( and Number of course, parameterized ) like :
    `public abstract T parse( String s );` ( and implemented specifically afterwards in all the subclasses of Number )

Comment: Remember that Java 1.0 didn't have generics. They came in Java 5. But even then, parseXxx returns a primitive, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) exists since JDK 1.0, Generics were only introduced in Java 1.5. Such a generic parsing method would therefore not been possible.

Concerning `Math.max`, it accepts only primitive types, which do not have any form of relationship to each other, and every primitive type needs to be declared separately to be supported.

Answer (score 2):

The various versions of `Math.max` have primitive arguments, not Numbers (which are Objects). What you suggest would require a boxing/unboxing operation each time the method is called which would not be as efficient as the current design.

Answer (score 0):

Parse instance methods would be pointless. You'd have to construct the immutable value before the parse.